# How can I prevent the seconds portion from displaying on the HTML5 time input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I add the HTML5 time input element like so:

...it shows me:

```
__:__:__
```

I don't want the third portion (seconds), just the hour and minutes. How can I get it to cease and desist from displaying the seconds portion, so that it's like this:

```
__:__
```

? Do I need to apply some CSS, or JavaScript/jQuery, or...???

Comment: In chrome I don't get seconds by default http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n98x0w2e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't show seconds, the third input is AM/PM.
IE/Firefox doesn't support this feature

```
<input type="time" name="yourtime"/>
```